# Can't connect to S3 in PrestoDB: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, parquet, presto

I am connecting to S3 Buckets to Apache Hive so that I can query the `Parquet` files in S3 directly through [PrestoDB](https://prestodb.io/). I am using HDP VM for PrestoDB by Teradata.

For this, I configured the `hive-site.xml` file and added my AWS Access Key and Secret Key in the `/etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml` file like:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.s3.aws-access-key</name>
  <value>something</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.s3.aws-secret-key</name>
  <value>some-other-thing</value>
</property>
```

Now, my S3 Bucket URL path where `Parquet` files reside looks like:

```
https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/sb.mycompany.com/someFolder/anotherFolder/?region=us-east-2&tab=overview
```

While Create an external table, I gave the location for S3 in the query as:

```
CREATE TABLE hive.project.data (... schema ...)
WITH ( format = 'PARQUET', 
  external_location = 's3://sb.mycompany.com/someFolder/anotherFolder/?region=us-east-2&tab=overview')
```

The Apache Hive **isn't able to connect** to S3 Buckets and giving this error with `--debug` flag:

```
Query 20180316_112407_00005_aj9x6 failed: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint

=========   TECHNICAL DETAILS   =========
[ Error message ]
Unable to load credentials from service endpoint

[ Session information ]
ClientSession{server=http://localhost:8080, user=presto, clientInfo=null, catalog=null, schema=null, timeZone=Zulu, locale=en_US, properties={}, transactionId=null, debug=true, quiet=false}

[ Stack trace ]
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint
    at com.amazonaws.auth.EC2CredentialsFetcher.handleError(EC2CredentialsFetcher.java:180)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.EC2CredentialsFetcher.fetchCredentials(EC2CredentialsFetcher.java:159)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.EC2CredentialsFetcher.getCredentials(EC2CredentialsFetcher.java:82)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.java:104)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4016)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getBucketRegionViaHeadRequest(AmazonS3Client.java:4478)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.fetchRegionFromCache(AmazonS3Client.java:4452)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.resolveServiceEndpoint(AmazonS3Client.java:4426)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1167)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1152)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.PrestoS3FileSystem.lambda$getS3ObjectMetadata$2(PrestoS3FileSystem.java:552)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.RetryDriver.run(RetryDriver.java:138)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.PrestoS3FileSystem.getS3ObjectMetadata(PrestoS3FileSystem.java:549)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.PrestoS3FileSystem.getFileStatus(PrestoS3FileSystem.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.isDirectory(FileSystem.java:1439)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.HiveMetadata.getExternalPath(HiveMetadata.java:719)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.HiveMetadata.createTable(HiveMetadata.java:690)
    at com.facebook.presto.spi.connector.classloader.ClassLoaderSafeConnectorMetadata.createTable(ClassLoaderSafeConnectorMetadata.java:218)
    at com.facebook.presto.metadata.MetadataManager.createTable(MetadataManager.java:505)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.CreateTableTask.execute(CreateTableTask.java:148)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.CreateTableTask.execute(CreateTableTask.java:57)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.DataDefinitionExecution.start(DataDefinitionExecution.java:111)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.QueuedExecution.lambda$start$1(QueuedExecution.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Network is unreachable
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1169)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.ConnectionUtils.connectToEndpoint(ConnectionUtils.java:47)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2CredentialsUtils.readResource(EC2CredentialsUtils.java:106)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2CredentialsUtils.readResource(EC2CredentialsUtils.java:77)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider$InstanceMetadataCredentialsEndpointProvider.getCredentialsEndpoint(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.java:117)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.EC2CredentialsFetcher.fetchCredentials(EC2CredentialsFetcher.java:121)
    ... 24 more
========= TECHNICAL DETAILS END =========
```

I even restarted my PrestDB server after I added the Keys. Next, I tried adding my properties to `/home/presto/.prestoadmin/catalog/hive.properties`:

```
connector.name=hive-hadoop2
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://localhost:9083
hive.allow-drop-table=true
hive.allow-rename-table=true
hive.time-zone=UTC
hive.metastore-cache-ttl=0s
hive.s3.use-instance-credentials=false
hive.s3.aws-access-key=something
hive.s3.aws-secret-key=some-other-thing
```

Again restarted the PrestoDB server but still the same issue.

I then modified the S3 Bucket location in query with bucket name only:

```
external_location = 's3://sb.mycompany.com'
```

And with `s3a` scheme as well:

```
external_location = 's3a://sb.mycompany.com'
```

But the same issue is still present. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is embarrassing. On the VM I was using, there were issues with the network adapter and so, the VM wasn't able to connect to the Internet. I corrected the adapter and it is working now.